# Why do my legs burn when I go for a walk?

Tags: exercise, pain, walking, burn

I am a nationally competitive athlete, so I workout up to 7 times a week. I'm perfectly healthy and don't have any injuries. I also don't have any unusual pain while I workout, other than muscle fatigue (which is to be expected). I took last week off from training for the holidays.

I went for an easy hike today with a friend and towards the end my thighs started to burn and itch, almost as if I had some kind of wind burn or something. Seeing as I had pants on and it was 60 degrees out, that seems like an unlikely cause. This isn't the first time this has happened, and it only ever happens when I go for a walk, but it doesn't happen every time. It begins to cease as soon as I stop exercising. If I try to push through the pain it only gets worse and worse until I give up. Anyone know why this might be, or how I can stop it?

Comment: Where, specifically, do you feel pain?

Comment: It's mostly concentrated in the inside and outside of my thighs, and its feels more like it's more on the surface of my skin than down in the muscle.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you have, but search Meralgia Paresthetica.

Comment: See a doctor. It could be nothing, but ignoring it won't make a serious problem go away.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally referred to as "[runner's itch](http://share.upmc.com/2015/03/prevent-runners-itch-save-workout/)".

It's caused by [capillaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary) in your skin being flushed with blood that they're not used to. Generally, it occurs in people who go for strenuous runs, hikes, or walks, when they're not conditioned to that type of workout.

I don't know what kind of national athlete you are, but I'm guessing that distance running (or really running in general) isn't part of your training program. If you do run frequently and still experience it, you might want to look at your clothing for some type of allergen.